# Laravel Ajax not updating

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have Laravel project for fire department and I have competitions with results of each team. I made a page where I can edit competition. In result controller

```
public function update (Request $request){
    $item = new Items();
    $item->item = $request->item;
    $item->data = $request->data;
    $item->miejscowosc = $request->miejscowosc;
    $item->gmina = $request->gmina;
    $item->wojewodztwo = $request->wojewodztwo;
    $item->poziom = $request->poziom;
    $item->komisja1 = $request->komisja1;
    $item->komisja2 = $request->komisja2;
    $item->komisja3 = $request->komisja3;
    $item->komisja4 = $request->komisja4;
    $item->komisja5 = $request->komisja5;
    $item->sedzia_glowny = $request->sedzia_glowny;
    $item->komisje_powolal = $request->komisje_powolal;
    $item->protesty = $request->protesty;
    $item->kontuzje = $request->kontuzje;
    $item->uwagi = $request->uwagi;
    $item->update();
    return 'Done';
}
```

When I change :

```
$item->update();
```

To :

```
$item->save();
```

It perfectly adds new competition. But when I have

```
$item->update();
```

It doesn't update.

Here is my ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#updateComp').click(function (event){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'item': $("#item").val(),
            'data': $('#data').val(),
            'miejscowosc': $('#miejscowosc').val(),
            'gmina': $('#gmina').val(),
            'wojewodztwo': $('#wojewodztwo').val(),
            'poziom': $('#poziom :selected').text(),
            'komisja1': $('#komisja1').val(),
            'komisja2': $('#komisja2').val(),
            'komisja3': $('#komisja3').val(),
            'komisja4': $('#komisja4').val(),
            'komisja5': $('#komisja5').val(),
            'sedzia_glowny': $('#sedzia_glowny').val(),
            'komisje_powolal': $('#komisje_powolal').val(),
            'protesty': $('#protesty').val(),
            'kontuzje': $('#kontuzje').val(),
            'uwagi': $('#uwagi').val()
        },
        success: function(data){$('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Dodano do bazy</div>')},
        error: function(){$('#alert').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Błąd, nie udało się dodać do bazy. Wprowadź dane ponownie</div>')}
    });
});
```

Do I have to change something in ajax code to make it work? Or is it another reason?
(really sorry for other language in project)

Comment: does it require an id ?? something like a way to point what to update??

Comment: After clicking "edit" button of competition it redirects to new subpage where it shows saved details from database so each competition has it's own subpage with id for example ".../results/details/1"

Comment: okay,. what i mean is something like this `$item->id = $post->get('id')` ??

Comment: I changed controller to:
`public function update (Request $request,$id){`
and added:
`$item->id = $id;`
But it doesn't help

Comment: From the official documentation: _The update method expects an array of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be updated._ Example: `->update(['delayed' => 1]);`

Comment: `$item = new Items();` you are creating a new item, what do you wish to update here? If you need an existing item, do `$item = Items::find($id);`

Comment: One more thing, when submitting a form, dont catch every single item, just submit them all together: `data: form.serialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For eloquent update, change your code like below code:

```
Items::find($id)->update(['column' => 'value']);
```

Here `$id` is id which you want to update the record. See [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)
**UPDATE**

```
$id = $request->id;//Item id to update...
$arrItem = array(
    'item' => $request->item,
    'data' => $request->data,
    .
    .
    .
    'uwagi' => $request->uwagi,
);

//Update item data...
Items::find($id)->update($arrItem);
```

Comment: So it should be like this?
`public function update ($id){

        Items::find($id)->update(['item' => 'item']);
        Items::find($id)->update(['data' => 'data']);`

Comment: @Sowam: Check my *UPDATE*

Comment: I got error "exception ".../MassAssignmentException" with message "item" in "../Model.php:232"

Comment: @Sowam: Read this section of [Laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Fields are not added as mass assignment, assign that like: `protected $fillable = ['item', 'data',.... 'uwagi'];`

Answer (score 0):

you have to send the item id to, so it can point which item need to update

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'your_url',
        data: {
            'id':$('#your_id_field'),
'your other field':$('#your_other_field),
.
.
        },
        success: function(data){$('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Dodano do bazy</div>')},
        error: function(){$('#alert').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Błąd, nie udało się dodać do bazy. Wprowadź dane ponownie</div>')}
    });
```

//controller, find the data using items model by searching the item's id

```
public function update (Request $request){
    $item = Items::find($request->get('id'));
    $item->item = $request->get('item');
    .....
    .....
    ....
    $item->update();
    return 'Done';
}
```

Comment: I changed it but I get error :
`Uncaught ReferenceError: $id is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (updatecomp.js:11)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (app.js:29)
    at HTMLButtonElement.g.handle (app.js:29)`

Comment: i mean you have to $('#your_field_id_item').val() @Sowam